# Is there any way to save credit card from paypal iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am using paypal iOS sdk . Currently I have sandbox account.There are two credit cards already saved in my account .When I login with paypal I can see the list of those credit cards .Also I can select card for the one tounch payment. Now my requirement is to store credit card to the account from iOS SDK . When I enter credit card detail is it possible to save that to the paypal ? So next time I will use same card from the list to make payment .

Comment: Please clarify. When using the iOS SDK, this is from the merchant side. It sounds like you are talking about the client side, as in saving the card for you to use in your own account for making payments.

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Robert: yes , right . It's about client side .

Comment: You should not have to use the SDK at all for this. You would add these credit cards on your PayPal account or through the PayPal app for you to then use later.